# If statement inside javascript variable

Tags: javascript

Some background: I have a javascript AJAX function which fetches xml output. The response is send to another javascript function which generates proper HTML. I loop through the xml file to grab content and build up code. The output should be rows with max 4 divs per row, where each div contains specific output of the loop.

Problem: I want to check how many divs are placed at the row, to decide whether to start a new row or not. I created a variable blocks which counts the amount of divs currently present, which increases with 1 after each div has been placed. If blocks=4 that means 4 divs are placed at the row, and the var blocks is set back to 0. I'd like to do this inside a javascript variable so I can perform everything client-side. When finished, I want to put the variable inside an HTML element via innerHTML.

Javascript so far (will be part of the loop):

```
var blocks=0;
var output=
        if(blocks==0)
        {
            '<div id="row"><div id="bl1">block1</div>';
            blocks+=1;
        }

    else if (blocks==1)
    {
        '<div id="bl2">block2</div>';
        blocks+=1;
    }

    else if(blocks==2)
    {
        '<div id="bl3">block3</div>';
        blocks+=1;
    }

    else if(blocks==3)
    {
        '<div id="bl4">block4</div></div>';
        blocks=0;
    }
```

When finished, I want to place the output variable inside another div:

```
document.getElementById("output-div").innerHTML=output;
```

Unfortunately this does not display any results.

Any thoughts?

Comment: so what's the problem you're facing?

Comment: the problem is my code doesn't give any results, so I'm wondering if anyone has any thoughts on how to fix/approach this? If there are 16 items in xml, the output should be 4 rows with 4 blocks(divs) per row (each block is a child div of the row div). The HTML for this must be created in/appended to the output variable which I can display with innerHTML.

Answer (score 0):

Above answers inspired me and I came up with this solution. Basically I keep track of the amount of blocks appended to a row. If 4 blocks are appended that means a new row must be created first.

```
<div id="output"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var list=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j'];
var index, len;
var row_number=0; // keep track of the row number we're appending blocks to
var block=0; // keep track of amount of blocks created in row_number

for (index = 0, len = list.length; index < len; ++index) {

    if(block==0) // if block=0 then a new row needs to be created
    {
        //create new row and append to output
        var div_row=document.createElement("div");
        div_row.className="logo-row"; // assign className for css purposes
        ++row_number;
        div_row.id="model_row_"+row_number; //assign id for append block purposes
        document.getElementById("output").appendChild(div_row);

        // create new (first) block and append to row
        var div_model=document.createElement("div");
        div_model.className='logo-block'+(block+1); // assign className for css purposes. Eack block could get different styling
        div_model.innerHTML=(list[index]);
        document.getElementById("model_row_"+row_number).appendChild(div_model);
        ++block;
    }

    else if (block==1 | block==2) // a second and third block can be created
    {
        var div_model=document.createElement("div");
        div_model.className='logo-block'+(block+1);
        div_model.innerHTML=(list[index]);
        document.getElementById("model_row_"+row_number).appendChild(div_model);
        ++block;
    }

    else // a fourth block can be created, after which a new row must be created to set block to 0
    {
        var div_model=document.createElement("div");
        div_model.className='logo-block'+(block+1);
        div_model.innerHTML=(list[index]);
        document.getElementById("model_row_"+row_number).appendChild(div_model);
        block=0;
    }
};

</script>
```

Thanks all for taking the time to answer and your suggestions!!